# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘db’)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My mongodb info etc. I entered it correctly, but every time I try to run the code, I keep getting this error. Attached is some of my code and a picture of the error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf4dK.png)

**Source Code**

```
const vars = require("../variables");

const url = vars.dbLink; // vars.dbLink
const dbName = "channels";

var database;

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

function connect(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, res) => {
    const db = res.db(dbName);
    database = db;
    return callback(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log(err)` inside the callback?

Comment: Why are you calling `MongoClient.connect` and not `client.connect`?

Comment: i got the error “MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option” now. I added this line console.log(err)
    const db = res.db(dbName);
    database = db;
    return callback(err);

Comment: I thought about this but didn't try one sec

Comment: I tried but TypeError: “connect” only accepts a callback at MongoClient.connect printed it out, so I pulled it back

Comment: I think the problem is with the mongodb connection url i will try and update this comment

Comment: I fixed my MongoDB connection url by editing  thx guys